# How do I specify custom JSON data for an ExtJS store?

Tags: json, extjs4

Say I have a JSON url that returns:

```
Results
    Users
        Samus Aran
        Ridley
    WorkOrders
        LABOR
            0
                .....
            1
                .....
        MATERIALS
            0
                .....
            1
                .....
```

Now, I have several `grid panels`.  One is `LABOR` and one is `MATERIALS`.  Obviously, I don't want to have to make another IO call so how can I create a store and point it to the existing JSON data that I already have?  Notice that it's a few layers deep.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there repeating instances of LABOR and MATERIALS within WorkOrders? Are there any other variables within the same "level" of nesting as LABOR and MATERIALS? Are you wanting data higher in the nesting chain in each of these stores (this one I think would be difficult to pull off)?

Comment: No Labor and Materials are two categories of WorkOrders.  So under Labor, there might be 0-10 records and under Materials there could be 0-10 records.  The only real difference between labor and materials is the name (type).  I could make Workorders contain all the records and put a `type=labor' or `type=materials` if it would be easier

Comment: I re-read your question and I do not know of a way to populate 2 stores with one call to the JSON. I am pretty sure you can use the same JSON from the server, but the only way I know to do it requires that you call it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm been thinking about this as a way to optimize the data loading in my applications. I never tried it but you might use the [loadData](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) method in the Store, but obviously this means that you need to load the data yourself. Maybe use a master store with url and then details store with  loadData.

Comment: That looks very promising.  I will check it out over the next few days.  Thanks!